# Set sample for a given set of commands in Stata

Tags: stata

I'm running several blocks of commands, where each block relates to a particular sub-sample of the dataset. The code within each block varies so I cannot run a `for` loop over all sub-samples. Moreover, blocks of codes are connected (some blocks outputs feed into other block as inputs), so I cannot just run separated do files.

At the moment I am running the do file by using the conditional `if sample == i` within each command (where the values of `sample` represent sub-samples of the dataset). Yet, this is time-consuming and less elegant. I am looking for a command that does something like:

```
set sample = 1
code 
code 
code 
set sample = 2
code
code
set sample = 3
code
code
```

So far I haven't found any Stata command/extension allowing me to do this. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think things like this are easier if you use a good text editor to quickly insert `if exp`s before commas or at the end of lines.

However, you can define mini programs in-line like this:

```
sysuse auto, clear

capture program drop block1
program define block1
syntax if
regress price mpg `if'
sum `if'
end
block1 if foreign==0
block1 if foreign==1    

capture program drop block2
program define block2
syntax if
tw hist price `if'
scatter price weight `if'
end

block2 if if price > 2000
block2 if foreign==1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of approaching this might be to use the preserve and restore commands. Your code would look like:

```
preserve
keep if x==1
code
code
code
restore
preserve
keep if x==2
code
...
```

Personally, I think this makes the code easy to follow, but the drawback is speed/efficiency because Stata is creating a temp file and then reloading the original data. So I would only use it if you are executing a lot of commands between the preserve and restore steps.

Comment: Since I use the result of a given block into other block of code, this is not the solution I need, as new variables created cannot be easily moved between blocks. However, I could export variables to a file and then call them again. That would make the code more complicated. I could give it a try and see how it works.

Comment: Ah, I see that now. I am assuming you already looked into the bysort commands? If you need to apply the same piece of code to each mutually exclusive subsample, that will do it...